# Jitter Physics Optimization

Tags: c#, optimization, mono, physics

I am using Jitter Physics in my C# apps over mono (mono is ported over arm) using embedded platform. I was looking at techniques to optimize the jitter code, is there any way we can follow to further optimize the jitter code performance wise.
Here is some profiling data for some shapes in jitter physics on PC and ARM 3 runs each. What can be done to increase performance?

```
Sr.No. Shapes          PC(ms)   | Embedded_Pfm(ms)  
1      BoxShape        34 40 34 | 599 575 569    
2      SphereShape     33 42 36 | 657 545 549    
3      CylinderShape   36 36 37 | 588 624 582    
4      ConeShape       33 35 36 | 569 586 618    
5      CapsuleShape    34 35 35 | 579 580 579    
6      TerrainShape    33 35 33 | 613 589 610    
7      ConvexHullShape 41 39 40 | 738 714 710
```

Comment: Please see the FAQ regarding signatures in posts. They only serve as additional bandwidth to our users.

Comment: Again... signatures are unwelcome on SO. Please do not add it again.